# Changing VIM Visual Block Shortcut

Tags: vim

I want to change the shortcut for visual block from Ctrl-v to something else. The issue is I am using a text expansion program on my base OS that is using the Ctrl-V shortcut for paste into my VNC session. If I change my paste shortcut in my VNC OS then my text expansion doesn't work.

Currently if I press Ctrl-v in vim then it pastes text, and if I press Ctrl-q then nothing happens. What is the easiest way to get my visual block functionality back without losing my text expansion, likely by changing the shortcut for visual block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remap it. I use line-wise visual mode more often than “character-wise,” so I have this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap v V
nnoremap V v
```

You could do something similar with Ctrl-v:

```
nnoremap v <c-v> " remap `v` to `Ctrl-v`
```

Comment: Ah - I was trying to remap the wrong way. Curiously I still couldn't use <ctrl-q>, even though I have read that is supposed to be the standard visual block fallback. This did work for me though:

nnoremap <c-b> <c-v>

Thanks.